# How to align text depending on other columns - e.g. centered depending on the visible part of two right-aligned columns

Tags: html, css

Seems that people downvoting this question (or voting for it being closed), didn't read it or didn't understand - so I edited to make it more clear.

I have a HTML table with two right-aligned columns and another column that "colspans" the other two. The text in the latter should be visually centered, so that the result looks like the third and fourth row in this example.

Is there some way to achieve "centered" text depending on the other columns with css?

The table is generated, all texts are read from database, column widths are given by percentage - I can't insert a hidden column or something. I could add classes to the `<td>` tags like I tried in this example.

```css
.centered { text-align : center; }
.guessed-center { text-align : center; padding-left: 16em; }
.right-aligned { text-align : right; }
```

```html
<table width=100% border=1>
<tr><td class="centered" colspan=2>Text to be visually centered is too far to the left</td></tr>
<tr><td class="right-aligned">First text</td><td class="right-aligned">Second text</td></tr>
<tr><td class="guessed-center" colspan=2>Text to be visually centered is more correct</td></tr>
<tr><td class="right-aligned">1st</td><td class="right-aligned">2nd</td></tr>
</table>

<table width=50% border=1>
<tr><td class="centered" colspan=2>Text to be visually centered is too far to the left</td></tr>
<tr><td class="right-aligned">First text</td><td class="right-aligned">Second text</td></tr>
<tr><td class="guessed-center" colspan=2>Text to be visually centered is more correct</td></tr>
<tr><td class="right-aligned">1st</td><td class="right-aligned">2nd</td></tr>
</table>
```

If I try to use some `padding-left`, I can manage to get the result for some fixed screen width, but if I resize the window the (absolute) column widths will change and the text won't be visually centered anymore, or like in the example layout is even messed up completely. Any idea for more sophisticated css to get the wanted result?

Comment: Why is this downvoted? If there's an obvious answer, please provide it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. I just removed the css property `padding-left: 16em;` from `.guessed-center`

```
.centered { text-align : center; }
.guessed-center { text-align : center; }
.right-aligned { text-align : right; }
```

Comment: When I remove the `padding-left` then it's mathematically centered, I want it centered visually, see the third line and also the jsfiddle - the second two lines get more to a visually centered - with your suggestion, the text is mathematically centered, and therefore too far to the left opposed to the two right-aligned columns